# how to check textfield is not empty and button enable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to check textfield is empty

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let text = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        if !text.isEmpty {
            self.completeRegisterBtn.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            self.completeRegisterBtn.isEnabled = false
        }
        
        return true
    }
```

This is my code but it is only check input new text.
I have already input textfields by data.
How can i check?

Furthermore not only want to check textfield but also a button(from 2 button) is selected check

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: After you set the data you need to call a function that checks all of the fields and sets the button state

Comment: My func can't call. It is delegate. But thank you so much! I can find another way

Comment: you can check textField.text.isEmpty and then you can perform the button enable or disable on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have attached the code how to check that textFiled is empty or not

```
let txtField = UITextField()
txtField.text = "testing"
if txtField.text != "" {
    btn_Pause.isEnabled = true
} else {
    btn_Pause.isEnabled = false
}
```

-> Using isEmpty function

```
if txtField.text?.isEmpty == true {
    btn_Pause.isEnabled = false
} else {
    btn_Pause.isEnabled = true
}
```

-> Using character count

```
if txtField.text?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
    btn_Pause.isEnabled = true
} else {
    btn_Pause.isEnabled = false
}
```

Comment: I want to check both button selected and textfield isnt empty

Answer (score 0):

Answer as per your comment:

```
if textField.text != "" && btn.isSelected {
            
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make function like this and call where you want to use this

```
func dataValidation(text: String) {

  btn.isEnable = (text.isEmpty ?? false) ? false : true 

}
```

how to use:

```
dataValidation(text: "test")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
if let text = textfield.text, !text.isEmpty {
    completeRegisterBtn.isEnabled = true
} else {
    completeRegisterBtn.isEnabled = false
}
```